# Empty String in an array of strings

Tags: java, arrays, string

I want to calculate the no of letters in words from 1 to 100. for example....

If the numbers 1 to 5 are written out in words: one, two, three, four, five,

then there are 3 + 3 + 5 + 4 + 4 = 19 letters used in total.

for which I have written the following code...

```
public static int helper(int a){

    String ones[]= {"","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten",
            "eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen","fifteen","sixteen","seventeen"
            ,"eighteen","nineteen"};

    String tens[]=  {"","","twenty","thirty","forty","fifty","sixty","seventy","eighty","ninety"};

    if(a<20){
        return ones[a].length();
    }
    else
        return tens[a/10].length();
}

public static int countLetters(int a){
    if(a==100)
        return 10;

    else if(a<20){

        return helper(a);
    }   

    else{

        return helper((a/10)*10)+ helper(a%10);
    }
}
```

The main function looks like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int result=0;
    for(int i=1;i<=100;i++){
        result+=countLetters(i);
    }
    System.out.println(result);

}
```

The correct answer for this problem is `864`. In the `String ones[]` array I used punctuation marks `" "` with space between them. The `result` returned was `872`which is incorrect but after removing space between them answer returned was `864`. I used `""` without space. I wonder why this happened..?

> Is there any logical aspect with respect to strings or string arrays for this problem ?

Comment: What do you mean? A space (`" "`) obviously affects the `length()` of a string.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that but I don't understand why would that affect my answer ? Because that value is never accessed in my code...it is just for providing correct indexes to the string values `one` `two` .....

Comment: I think you should take a look at my problem and code for better understanding....

Comment: If you are trying to count the number of letters in the string using `String.length()`, you need all of the characters in the string to be letters - spaces aren't letters (as in, [`Character.isLetter(' ') == false`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter(char))), so don't include them in your count.

Comment: I have not used spaces in string values whose letters are to be counted ....but used an empty string at index 0 of the ones[] because I wanted "one" at index 1 , "two" at index 2...just like that..

Comment: @Adityakumar, but `a%10` can presumably be `0` sometimes, right? Which would make you count `" "` as 1.

Comment: Yes , I understand that now thankyou very much....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only happens when you have the `" "` in the `ones` array.

If you have 20, you get the length of `"twenty"` + the length of `helper(a%10)` which is `helper(0)`, which returns the length of `" "`. So you get the length of `"twenty"` + the length of `" "`.

This happens for 20, 30, 40, 50, 60 ,70 ,80 and 90. 8 times. That's why you see the 872.

The easiest fix is just making the first string `""`, like you did, but this would work too:

```
// return helper((a/10)*10)+ helper(a%10);
return helper((a/10)*10) + (a%10 == 0 ? 0 : helper(a%10));
```

Answer (score 1):

A space in a String also adds to the length of a String for example:

```
"foo bar".length() --> 7
" foo bar ".length() -->9
"foobar".length() -->6
```

If you want to avoid having this problem and remove the outer space use trim.

```
"foo bar".trim().length() --> 7
" foo bar ".trim().length() -->7
"foobar".trim().length() -->6
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

What does this line of code calculate when value of `a` is 20?

`return helper((a / 10) * 10) + helper(a % 10);`

Your answer is in the calculation of this calculation. So, let's solve this out.

`return helper((20 / 10) * 10) + helper(20 % 10);`

which becomes:

`return helper(20) + helper(0);`

and in call against `helper(0)`, your method executes this particular condition:

```
    if(a<20){
        return ones[a].length();
    }
```

So, although you start your loop's iteration from 1 doesn't mean that index 0 for array `ones` is not being traversed.